# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_login' in docker container even after installing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I created  a flask and mysql app and put them in docker container as two services(the app and the db). The build went well but the project is very dependent on "flask login module". I cant even create my db tables in the container without it. I installed the package but still I get the error below.

```
root@eea003fece36:/tourmeapp# ./web_dynamic/db/db_engine.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tourmeapp/./web_dynamic/db/db_engine.py", line 7, in <module>
    from models import User, User_info, Message, Base, engine
  File "/tourmeapp/web_dynamic/db/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from flask_login import UserMixin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_login'
```

When I enter the docker app python Interpreter and do test below it works fine. the module is available

```
from flask_login import current_user
```

So i don't understand why it would not import inside my project files. Does anybody know why?

Dokerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


WORKDIR /tourmeapp

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

RUN python3 -m pip install flask-login
RUN pip3 freeze -> requirements.txt


COPY . /tourmeapp


CMD [ "python3", "app.py"]
```

Database image

```
mysql:8.0
```

Requrements.txt file

```
click==8.0.3
Flask==2.0.2
Flask-Login==0.5.0
greenlet==1.1.2
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.2
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
mysqlclient==2.0.3
SQLAlchemy==1.4.26
Werkzeug==2.0.2
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the library installation command on the docker file?  Eg.  COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

Comment: Yes I did, I even updated the question with more details about it, including the requirements.txt and dockerfile configs.

Comment: Have you tried testing your project locally?! Can you enter inside your container app and install this module with pip

Comment: Yes I did all that. The project runs perfectly locally. Also the docker conteiner runs but the missing module is the problem. I checked into the docker container terminal and tried installing in there. Still nothing works, same error. But apparently it can perfectly import in the container "python3 interpreter shell". So I cant figure where the problem is.